# Does $P(X_i<c)>1-\varepsilon$ imply $ P(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i<c)>1-\varepsilon? $

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be possibly dependent random variables on $(0,1)$ satisfying
$$
P(X_i<c)>1-\varepsilon, 
$$
where $c\in (0,1)$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

Does it hold that
$$
P(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i<c)>1-\varepsilon? 
$$

If they are fully dependent ($X_i=X_j$) then this trivially holds. If they are independent, then this holds at least in the limit from LLN. Does it hold in general?

Comment: I would understand "fully dependent" to mean $\sigma(X_i) = \sigma(X_j),$ rather than $X_i = X_j.$ Alas, my understanding is mathematically equivalent to $X_i = u(X_j)$ for an invertible measurable function $u.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $X_1$ to be $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and let $X_2=1-X_1$. Then $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^2 X_i = 1/2$.

Let $c=1/2$ and let $\epsilon = 2/3$. Then $\mathbb{P}(X_1<c)=1/2>1-\epsilon$, and same for $X_2$. But $\mathbb{P}((X_1+X_2)/2<1/2)=0$.